# how to add two or more urls to active class for sub menu with php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, submenu

```
<?php echo (uri_string() == 'user/profile') ? 'm-submenu__item--active' : ''; ?>
```

I want to add 'user/profile' and 'user/setting' or more url into this line.How can i do it using only this php line.

Comment: Please be more elaborate on your topic .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `in_array` method

```
<?php echo in_array(uri_string(), ['user/profile', 'user/setting']) ? 'm-submenu__item--active' : ''; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use regex. You will be doing array on all possible 'user' routes?